# Using MySQL to INSERT a value into a single table n times

Tags: mysql, for-loop, sql-insert

I have been searching and searching via google, so apologies if this has already been answered or is very simple.

I am working on a MySQL project where I need to add the same value multiple times. For instance, the following code is adding one 'Ant' to my table:

```
INSERT INTO `bugtypes` (`BugTypeID`, `BugTypeName`) VALUES
(1, 'Ant');
```

In order to populate the table with 100 'Ants', I would have to run this command over a hundred times. I know there is a better way to do this, such as a for loop, but I keep screwing up the syntax. Currently this is what I am working with and am continually receiving errors:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addAnts(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 100 THEN
      INSERT INTO `bugtypes` (`BugTypeID`, `BugTypeName`) VALUES
      (p1, 'Ant');
      ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
  SET @x = p1;
END;
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:

Here is the error I have been receiving:

https://i.gyazo.com/b71ee1c7d6ad41d4a347d97d7cfb6578.png

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: what error are you getting the syntax looks correct

Comment: The reason I need to do this is related to an assignment for my App Dev class. Probably one of those "you would never do this in real life, but you should know your way around your code" type of questions.

Comment: I will edit the above post with a picture of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found the solution, very similar to @Barmar, except it is simpler. I learned how to add AUTO_INCREMENT to my column BugTypeID thanks to @Barmar as well and that allowed me to do this. Thanks for helping me and pointing me in the right direction guys!

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate()
BEGIN
  DECLARE total INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE total <= 100 DO
    INSERT INTO `bugtypes` (`BugTypeName`) VALUES ('Ant');
    SET total = total + 1;
  END WHILE;
END//

delimiter ;

CALL doiterate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect part of the problem (and we're just guessing here) might be the statement `DELIMITER`.

It's not at all clear what client we are executing from (MySQL command line?) so please excuse me if this isn't an issue. But there's no demonstration in the question that a simple procedure can be created, whether we are over that hump.  So before we start messing with more involved procedure syntax, let's make sure we can create and execute a simple procedure.  Let's walk before we try to run.

From the MySQL command line client, connected to MySQL as a user with sufficient privileges, let's try something really simple:

```
USE mydatabase ;

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE addAnts $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addAnts (p1 INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `bugtypes` (`BugTypeID`, `BugTypeName`) VALUES (77, 'Ant');
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL addAnts(77);

SELECT `BugTypeID`, `BugTypeName` FROM `bugtypes` WHERE BugTypeID = 77;
```

Are there any error messages? And if so, what is the *exact* text of the error messages?

Once we are over that hump, we can start modifying the syntax within the procedure.

Comment: I am just using the mySQL local host page to upload a .sql file and run it. I am pretty new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a single query with multiple `VALUES` lists.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addAnts(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  @first = TRUE;
  @query = "INSERT INTO `bugtypes` (`BugTypeID`, `BugTypeName`) VALUES ";
  WHILE p1 < 99 do
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF NOT @first THEN
        @query = CONCAT(@query, ",");
    ELSE
        @first = FALSE;
    END IF
    @query = CONCAT(@query, "(", p1, ", 'Ant')");
  END WHILE;
  PREPARE @stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE @stmt;
  SET @x = p1;
END;
```

BTW, is there a reason you're not using `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `BugTypeID` field?

Comment: No, to be honest, I am just getting the hang of all this. What does the AUTO_INCREMENT do? Does it automatically count from 1-n so I don't have to use p1?

Comment: If you add the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option to the primary key of a table, the database automatically assigns values 1, 2, 3, ... to that column by default when you insert rows.

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html